# How to query distinct count distibution in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cardinality

Cardinality aggregation query calculates an approximate count of distinct values. How we can calculate the cardinality distribution of documents?

For example suppose we have:

```
a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,d,d,e
```

and distinct count distribution is:

```
3: 2 # count of distint element that have 3 occurnes (a, b) 
2: 2 # c, d
1: 1 # e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you cannot do aggregations like this.

But, using `transform` API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-examples.html) you could create a new index to do a simple `terms` aggregation:

```
PUT _transform/so
{
  "dest" : {
   "index" : "my-so"
  },
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index"
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": { 
      "country": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "letter"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "cardinality": {
        "value_count": { 
          "field" : "letter"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you:

```
[
    {
      "country" : "a",
      "cardinality" : 22
    },
    {
      "country" : "b",
      "cardinality" : 4
    },
    {
      "country" : "c",
      "cardinality" : 5049
    }...
```

Then, you can use simple terms or histogram aggregation:

```
GET /my-so/_search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs": {
    "cc": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cardinality"
      }
    }
  }
}
```