# Get a histogram of the count of unique values in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have docs that looks like this in ES:

```
{
  "ipAddress": "w",
  ...
},
{
  "ipAddress": "x",
  ...
},
{
  "ipAddress": "x",
  ...
},
{
  "ipAddress": "x",
  ...
},
{
  "ipAddress": "y",
  ...
},
{
  "ipAddress": "y",
  ...
},
{
  "ipAddress": "z",
  ...
},
...
```

I'm looking to understand the distribution of the number of events per ip address.  In other words, for the data above, i want the results:

```
numOfEvents | numOfOccurences |
_______________________________
     1      |       2      (2 times, w and z)
_______________________________
     2      |       1      (1 time, y)
_______________________________
     3      |       1      (1 time, x)
_______________________________
```

The cardinality of `ipAddress` is very large, so it's infeasible to get a terms aggregation by ip and build the histogram on the client side.  I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71055157/how-to-query-distinct-count-distibution-in-elasticsearch) which seems to indicate that this isn't possible? A transform table is the only option?  We're on an older version of ES that we need to upgrade to use this, and I would imagine using this transform approach would use up a lot of space (currently about 2TB of data).

Comment: Hi Mike, what is the type of ipAddress field? If the field type is IP rather than using term aggregation you can use the `IP range aggs` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-iprange-aggregation.html

Comment: `so it's infeasible to get a terms aggregation` can you clarify why?
+
 also, what do you think about filtering aggregation with buckets? for example  numOfEvent-2023, numOfEvents-2022